# Enable X11 Forwarding with Net::SSH in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

For some actions, I need to ssh with `ssh -X user@host`. Is it possible for Ruby's [Net::SSH](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) to use this (with emphasis on the `-X`)?

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', password: 'password') do |ssh|
  # Do work
end
```

I'm not currently seeing any options to enable X11 Forwarding. Are there any options for this?

**Update**

More information found in the [SSH Manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201)

> -X     Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
>        basis in a configuration file.
>
> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
>        ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
>        user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
>        through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able
>        to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
>
> For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
>        extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the `ssh -Y`
>        option and the `ForwardX11Trusted` directive in ssh_config(5) for
>        more information.

**Background**

Essentially I am automating a process. Users right now ssh into a server and run some commands with the `-X` option. I'm told that the `-X` option is a requirement. I've successfully used `Net::SSH` to do the commands, but I'm still told they need the `-X` option to present.

Comment: What do you mean by *to enable X11 Forwardin* ?

Comment: Just updated my question :) Thanks for asking! I'm hoping for a way to mimic `ssh -X` with `Net::SSH`.

Comment: just got hit by this problem too. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ended up talking with the people who required me to do it, and had them change their end so it was no longer required. But this would still be a great question to be answered for those who need it.